# Putting ArrayList of ArrayList into a bundle, parcelable

Tags: java, android, parcelable

Hi i need to put an ArrayList < ArrayList< String>> in my class yet retain its parcebility

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quotes;
```

I have tried

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList(QUOTE_ARRAY, quotes);
```

i get 'quotes' underlined in red and it says "required: java.util.ArrayList< ?extends android.os.Parcel able>"

how can i make the ArrayList inside the parent ArrayList parcelable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an ArrayList is not a parcelable, I would suggest encapsulating the ArrayList of strings in an class that implements parcelable. Then just use an ArrayList containing that object type.